# AngularJS use one Provider to config other Provider

Tags: angularjs, provider

I use a custom provider to read a local JSON file. From this file i need the value to config another custom provider - in the same module/config.

How can i do that?

Attention: I can not map both providers to one, ore something similar workarounds. I have to use both providers.

thanks isa

Comment: I believe providers can be injected to each other; so make the "JSON reader" provider depend on the other and, when the JSON is read, configure it.

Comment: niko, funny sideinfo... sitting right now in athens airport while trying to fix this problem :-) my problem is, that i need to config the other provider in the config of the module... i can (must) do it only there....

Comment: I hope you enjoyed your stay :) So the providers must/can not know about each other? Still you could inject both of them to the module config, let the one read the JSON and then configure the other. Or am I not getting the problem?

Comment: sorry for my late response.... i do what you said... i make the json provider depend on the other... so it works as i want :-) thanks!